# Dynamic Link Count no Klicks

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I like to short an URL with Firebase to use this Shortlink for an QR-Code. So I setted up a new Project in Firebase, goes in to the Dynamic Links Section and created a new URL-prefix like https://mysitename.page.link.

After this I created a new Shortlink like https://mysitename.page.link/Posx.

Now, when I put this link into my Browser, it works correctly and the ShortURL took me to the right Place.

But in Firebase, the Counter of Klicks for this ShortURL stands still at 0.

How can I get Analytics Data like Google URL Shorterer Service bevore?

Thanks for Help.

Comment: NO Ideas anyone?